# How to control (start, abort) an external program via a HTML page using ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to build a web-based 'configuration wizard' that asks the user some values, renders them into a config file and then lets the user start a server-side program using this config.

I chose ExpressJS, since it seemed to be relatively light-weight and easy to learn. However, I have no experience with web programming or JavaScript whatsoever.

Somehow I managed to build the wizard pages, although it feels like I'm using something horribly wrong (the application is basically stateless and drags the user values through different HTML pages by rendering the previous values into hidden fields in the new page's form ...).

After all the wizard pages, there comes a 'control' page, where the user can see (and edit) the computed configuration. The page has two buttons:

One runs a program to validate the configuration and check for errors. This is done via `child_process.execSync(...)` (since it doesn't take long) and works quite well.

The other one is supposed to start a long-running task in the background. While the task is running, buttons on the page should be disabled, except for an 'Abort' button, which should kill the background task (not yet implemented). After the task is finished, the page should be reloaded with enabled buttons and a status field containing whether the task was successful. Unfortunately, I can't get this to work.

I'm using ExpressJS with pug.

control.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var utils = require('./utils');
var createError = require('http-errors');
var child_process = require('child_process');

router.all('/', function(req, res,next) {
  var status = null;
  if ([req.app.locals.buttons.doStuff].includes(req.body.submit)) {
    next();
  }
  switch(req.body.submit) {
    case req.app.locals.buttons.validate:
      try {
        utils.validate(req.body.config_text); // helper function that basically calls an external program via child_process.execSync
        status = "config.yaml is valid!"
      } catch (err) {
        status = "config.yaml is invalid: " + err
      }
      break;
    case req.app.locals.buttons.doStuff:
      res.render('control', { title: req.app.locals.title, buttons: req.app.locals.buttons, config_data: req.body.config_text, status: status, disabled: true });
      return;
  }
  res.render('control', { title: req.app.locals.title, buttons: req.app.locals.buttons, config_data: req.body.config_text, status: status });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var status = null;
  console.log("Entering command mode: " + req.body.submit);
  switch(req.body.submit) {
    case req.app.locals.buttons.doStuff:
      status = "Doing stuff ... this will take a while (timeout after 1h)."
      console.log(status);
      child_process.exec("doStuff arg1 arg2 arg3", {cwd: req.app.locals.dostuff_directory, timeout: 3600000}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        status = "doStuff successfully finished!"
        if (err) {
          status = "Error while doing stuff: \n" + stderr;
        }
        res.render('control', { title: req.app.locals.title, buttons: req.app.locals.buttons, config_data: req.body.config_text, status: status });
      });
      break;
    default:
      status = "Unknown command: " + req.body.submit;
      res.render('control', { title: req.app.locals.title, buttons: req.app.locals.buttons, config_data: req.body.config_text, status: status });
      break;
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and the corresponding control.pug:

```
extends layout // basically just places the content block into <body>

block content
  h1= title
  h3 Control Page

  form(method="post", autocomplete="off")
    label(for="config_text") config.yaml
    textarea(name="config_text", cols="70", rows="35")
      = config_data
    pre
      code(name="status")
        = status
    div(class="controls")
      input(type="submit", name="submit", value=buttons.validate, disabled=disabled)
      input(type="submit", name="submit", value=buttons.doStuff, disabled=disabled)
      if (disabled)
        input(type="submit", name="submit", value=buttons.abort)
```

If I click the 'doStuff' button, the buttons are disabled, but the task doesn't run and I get `error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I guess I could use `child_process.execSync` as a workaround instead, since that seems to work, but I assume that it will freeze the page while the task is running. I also have the feeling I should use a different method to react to button clicks than HTML `form` tags.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that child_process.exec is essentially asynchronous - you have to use a callback function to get the result. That callback won't be executed for some time. In the meantime, control is returned to the method which executed child_process.exec. That will then finish executing and send a HTTP response to the client. You can't add things to the response after it's been sent. You need to make the main function wait until the doStuff task has finished.

Comment: Although having said that, it's probably a bad design pattern to have a 1hr task triggered and executed all within the context of a single HTTP request. The user will just see a spinning circle if they execute this from a browser. This is the exact use case for scheduled background jobs (e.g. triggered by cron or whatever the hosting O/S provides). So the express code will receive the request, get the details of the task and then log that to a job queue (e.g. it could just be a database table). It then returns a "we're working on it" response to the client.

Comment: That response could also include a link to a URL where the user can go to check the status of their task and see if it's completed or not (and maybe even see progress, if there's a way to monitor that). They can refresh that page (or it can refresh itself) to see the latest status. Or alternative you could simply promise to notify the user (e.g. by email or SMS, if you have such details) when the job is complete. Depends on your requirements.

Comment: meanwhile, a background job runs regularly and takes the next job from the queue for processing. It runs it, and when complete it updates the queue entry to say it's completed, and moves on to the next one. Or if there's an error or other problem it can set a different status in the queue entry. Maybe you can have a retry system or other failsafe. It's a much more robust and user-friendly architecture.